# Skip validation for related objects - rails activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

```
class Author
  has_many :books

  validates :email, :presence => true
end

class Book
  belongs_to :author

  validates :title, :presence => true
end
```

Skipping validations is easy:

```
a = Author.new
a.save(:validate => false)
```

However, I need skip author validations when creating a book without skipping books validations, like this:

```
b = Book.new
b.title = "A Book"

b.author = Author.last
b.save
```

Comment: Any reason you don't create a valid author first and then create the book?

Comment: It`s just a particular case from my system.

Comment: You don't have `validates_associated :author` in Book, and you're not modifying Author. I'm surprised it's validating Author at all. In the past I have used a boolean db column to override validations.

Answer (score 0):

I quite did not understand your question. In your example you are not creating any new author object:

```
>     b = Book.new
>     b.title = "A Book"
>     
>     b.author = Author.last
>     b.save
```

If you are trying to create a new author without an email, can't you just do:

```
b = Book.new
b.title = "A Book"

author = Author.new
author.save(:validate => false)

b.author = author
b.save
```

Hmm... maybe I'm just missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 0):

Since author validation seems not so important while saving your model, you could write your Book model like this:

```
class Book
  belongs_to :author, :validate => false

  validates :title, :presence => true
end
```

This way, authors validations will be skipped while saving.

Comment: Note that `:validate` is `false` [by default](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to-label-Options) so no point writing it like that.